# dealing with arrays in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-4, amazon-ses

I'm trying to use the Amazon AWS SDK to use SES email functionality, the requirements for that function is quite nasty, it just doesn't look right how I'm doing it although it works.

**Function Reference**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Ses.SesClient.html#_sendEmail

```
$ses->sendEmail(array(
    'Source' => 'no-reply@test.com',
    'Destination' => array('ToAddresses' => $to),
    'Message' => array(
        'Subject' => array('Data' => $subject),
        'Body' => array('Text' => array('Data' => $message)),
    ),
));
```

I see this blog post here uses dot notation, how can I do similar as Laravel does seem to work this way at least for retrieving the config.
http://www.alexkorn.com/blog/2011/04/sending-email-aws-php-with-amazonses/

```
$amazonSes->send_email(AWS_SES_FROM_EMAIL,
        array('ToAddresses' => array($to)),
        array(
            'Subject.Data' => $subject,
            'Body.Text.Data' => $message,
        )
);
```

Comment: what happens when you use dot notation?

Comment: It tells me Body is required, Source is required, the aws sdk is telling me i'm basically not passing in the right format